# Magento Advance Search - Drop down box of color - Option "All" not coming

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento project where advanced search page is already built. I have one attribute called "Color" having following values and also have made attribute property Yes for advance search.

Blue
Green 
Yellow.

I also have updated form.php of mage/...so that instead of multiselect, drop down box will come.

Now, in advance search Color drop down, I am not able to set "All" option. I want this because currently Blue is preselected and in each search, this criteria is added. I have not done any updates in other pages.

Please help me.

Jeff

Comment: Hey got the answer.. Go to app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form.php ..

Comment
        if (is_array($options) && count($options)>2) {
            //$extra = 'multiple="multiple" size="4"';
   $extra = '';
            $name.= '[]';
        }
        else {
            array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('All')));
        }

and put 
array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('All')));

So this will show dropdown box with All as selected.

Comment: you should post this as an actual answer below. That will give you code formatting and allow others to benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a vary useful question and @Jeff's comment is a great solution.
I report it with better formatting:

Comment out this code:

```
 // 2 - avoid yes/no selects to be multiselects
        if (is_array($options) && count($options)>2) {
          $extra = 'multiple="multiple" size="4"';
          $name.= '[]';
        }
        else {
          array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('All')));
        }
```

And replace it with this:

```
        array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('All')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create select box for any drop-down attributes like color, manufacturer etc and use for search form or any custom form page.
Here goes the related article:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/magento-utility-function-how-to-easily-create-select-box-for-drop-down-attributes

Cheers!!